# Including component in another component without declaring in NgModule

Tags: angular

In the latest angular release, to include one component in another component, it must be declared in NgModule([angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Component-decorator.html)).

*A component must belong to an NgModule in order for it to be usable by another component or application. To specify that a component is a member of an NgModule, you should list it in the declarations field of that NgModule.*

Is there any way i can include a component in another without declaring in NgModule as i might have hundreds of components in application and declaring them in NgModule is painful.

I tried using "entryComponents" to include a component without declaring it in the NgModule but throwing script error.

Including one component in another component is supported till [2.0.0-rc.5 (2016-08-09)](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) release. But it is removed from 2.0.0-rc.6 (2016-08-31).

Comment: How is declaring hundreds of components in hundreds of different places less painful than in one place?

Comment: `entryComponents` is in `NgModule` as well anyway. I don't really get what your question is about.

Comment: It was supported till rc5. In rc6 t NgModule were introduced and directives:[ ] in metadta of component is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as the docs states
You need a component to be part of a module.

What you can do is download angular-cli and use its scaffolding function `ng generate component myconponent`.  Angular cli will automatically add that component to its parent's module in the declarations array.

Comment: This is possible now with angular standalone components